# GDPR - Right of Access From Processor

Tags: data-ownership, data-protection, gdpr

If my organisation is processing data on behalf of a controller, does the data subject have access rights through the processor, or must Subject Access Requests (SARs) go through the controller?

If the processor then becomes a controller (or joint controller) through activities that create new data about the individual, should an SAR disclose all data about said individual, or only data not passed in by the original controller?

Comment: For anyone else wondering the same, I think Article 14 answers the question: https://gdpr-info.eu/art-14-gdpr/